# Merge into not updating row with the same non pk value that needs to be unique

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, data-warehouse

Help!!

I have a written a query to merge data from a view into a data warehouse table

The view has data from 3 different databases

I need to update a row in the data warehouse if TFN (tax file number, not a pk) is the same

However only 2 of the tables (in Australia) store the TFN, the third (Not in Aus) does not and the TFN in the view for these rows is null

I have tried a few things but cant get the result I'm after

This attempt runs ok but inserts the 2nd row with the same TFN

```
MERGE INTO DWCUSTOMER d
using CUST_ALL_VIEW V
ON ((d.TFN = v.TFN AND d.COUNTRY = 'Australia') OR (d.CUSTOMER_ID = v.CUSTOMER_ID AND d.COUNTRY <> 'Australia'))
when matched then update set D.OCCUPATION = V.OCCUPATION, D.CITY = V.CITY, D.STATE = V.STATE,
d.POSTAL_CODE = v.POSTAL_CODE, d.REGION = v.REGION, d.COUNTRY = v.COUNTRY
when not matched then insert
(CUSTOMER_KEY, CUSTOMER_ID, CITY, STATE, POSTAL_CODE, GENDER, TFN, OCCUPATION, REGION, COUNTRY)
values
(DWCUSTSEQ.NEXTVAL, v.CUSTOMER_ID, v.CITY, v.STATE, v.POSTAL_CODE, v.GENDER, v.TFN, v.OCCUPATION, v.REGION, v.COUNTRY);
```

Another attempt I made does not work (as I later worked out, you can't have a unique/distinct on just one of many columns), but it demonstrates better exactly what I am trying to achieve (I think :/)

```
merge into DWCUSTOMER D
using (select SOURCE_ROWID, TABLE_NAME, CUSTOMER_ID, CITY, STATE,
POSTAL_CODE, GENDER, REGION, COUNTRY, UNIQUE(TFN) AS TFN, OCCUPATION
from CUST_ALL_VIEW
where COUNTRY = 'Australia'
UNION
select *
from CUST_ALL_VIEW
WHERE COUNTRY <> 'Australia') v
on ((D.TFN = V.TFN and D.COUNTRY = 'Australia') or (D.CUSTOMER_ID = V.CUSTOMER_ID and D.COUNTRY <> 'Australia'))
when matched then update set D.OCCUPATION = V.OCCUPATION, D.CITY = V.CITY, D.STATE = V.STATE,
d.POSTAL_CODE = v.POSTAL_CODE, d.REGION = v.REGION, d.COUNTRY = v.COUNTRY
when not matched then insert
(CUSTOMER_KEY, CUSTOMER_ID, CITY, STATE, POSTAL_CODE, GENDER, TFN, OCCUPATION, REGION, COUNTRY)
values
(DWCUSTSEQ.NEXTVAL, v.CUSTOMER_ID, v.CITY, v.STATE, v.POSTAL_CODE, v.GENDER, v.TFN, v.OCCUPATION, v.REGION, v.COUNTRY);
```

Suggestions to fix??

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 0):

(late answer is LATE) Try changing the TFN compare to this:

```
ISNULL(d.TFN,-9) = isnull(v.TFN,-9)
```

(where -9 is obviously an invalid TFN - just to get around the mysteries of SQL Null comparisons)